# JavaFX CheckBoxTreeItem: Graphic disappears if graph is extended

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I have a bunch of `CheckBoxTreeItem<MyClass>` to build a hierarchy of items using a `TreeView`. I create a new object and add it to its parent like this:

```
CheckBoxTreeItem<MyClass> created = new CheckBoxTreeItem<MyClass>(
    myClassObj, new Label("label");

parent.getChildren().add(created); // parent is another CheckBoxTreeItem
```

Besides that, I use a `CellFactory` like this:

```
myTreeView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.<MyClass>forTreeView());
```

**Problem:** If I collapse / expand the the items in the GUI, the Label occasionally disappears, leaving a blank space where it should be rendered. So it is kind of there, but not visible. However, the text right to the `Label` (from the `MyClass` object) is shown. I observed the problem with my own classes extending `CheckBoxTreeItem` and `CheckBoxTreeCell`, but the problem seems to be more general, as it is reproducable with the default classes. If you have an idea, I'm thankful for any hints.

**EDIT:** Here is a MCVE - just expand and collapse a few of the checkboxes to observe the strange behaviour:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTreeCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TreeViewSample3 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        //create the root element
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> rootItem = 
            new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("Root", new Label("Root"));

        rootItem.setExpanded(true); 
        rootItem.setIndependent(true);

        final TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<String>(rootItem);  
        tree.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.<String>forTreeView());  

        //put some checkboxes to the tree
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            final CheckBoxTreeItem<String> child = 
                new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("2nd level", new Label("tier 2"));
            final CheckBoxTreeItem<String> grandChild = 
                new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("3rd level", new Label("tier 3"));

            child.getChildren().add(grandChild);
            rootItem.getChildren().add(child);

        }

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(tree);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Screenshot of the error. It only occurs if you repeatedly expand/collapse items in the tree. It seems like the item at the bottom are somehow not correctly rendered. Note, the used version is 8.40.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Works perfectly for me, which version of JavaFX are you using?

Comment: I see the behavior described in 8u20, it appears to be fixed in 8u40.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha /James_D: I have built the example using the versions 8u20, 8u25, and 8u40. The issue occured in all of them. I'm working on a 64bit Windows 8.1 machine by the way. I provided a screenshot to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I have 8u40 and see the same error as shown in the screenshot above

Comment: It does not work on Linux using Oracle JDK 8u40 either.

Comment: It does not work on win7 Oracle JDK 8u60 either.