# JavaFX CheckBoxTreeItem graphic disappear/appear when expanding/collapsing

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I'm trying to make TreeView with CheckBoxTreeItems. When I collapse/expand a CheckBoxTreeItems the image I set up does not display correctly. I googled but I couldn't find correct answer. On Stack Overflow, I found a similar problem, but I didn't get a valid answer.

E.g

[JavaFX CheckBoxTreeItem graphic disappear when siblings collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621772/javafx-checkboxtreeitem-graphic-disappear-when-siblings-collapse)

[JavaFX CheckBoxTreeItem: Graphic disappears if graph is extended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960294/javafx-checkboxtreeitem-graphic-disappears-if-graph-is-extended)

Any ideas?

```
public class ClientApplication extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        ImageView folderIcon = new ImageView();
        Image folderImage = new Image("image/folder.png");
        folderIcon.setImage(folderImage);
        folderIcon.setFitWidth(16);
        folderIcon.setFitHeight(16);
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> rootItem = new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("folder", folderIcon);
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            CheckBoxTreeItem<String> checkBoxTreeItem = new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("Sample" + (i + 1), folderIcon);
            rootItem.getChildren().add(checkBoxTreeItem);
        }

        final TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<String>(rootItem);
        tree.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.<String>forTreeView());
        tree.setRoot(rootItem);
        tree.setShowRoot(true);


        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(tree);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w6Qg.png)

I tried to use the ideas provided by @Jai,But when I click the expand/collapse icon, there is still a problem.Attachment is a screenshot.Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1YhA.png)

Answer (score 0):

`ImageView` is a JavaFX control. This means that each instance represents a unique control you see on your screen. You should never use the same instance for multiple locations in your GUI.

On the other hand, `Image` represents an image (i.e. an array of pixel data), so it is reusable.

This should work:

```
@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) {
    final Image folderImage = new Image("image/folder.png");

    CheckBoxTreeItem<String> rootItem = new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("folder", createImageView(folderImage));
    rootItem.setExpanded(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> checkBoxTreeItem = new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("Sample" + (i + 1), createImageView(folderImage));
        rootItem.getChildren().add(checkBoxTreeItem);
    }

    final TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<String>(rootItem);
    tree.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.<String>forTreeView());
    tree.setRoot(rootItem);
    tree.setShowRoot(true);


    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(tree);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    stage.show();
}

private ImageView createImageView(Image folderImage) {
    ImageView folderIcon = new ImageView();
    folderIcon.setImage(folderImage);
    folderIcon.setFitWidth(16);
    folderIcon.setFitHeight(16);

    return folderIcon;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.I tried it.But when I click the expand/collapse icon, there is still a problem.Attachment is a screenshot.If you have time, please help me look at it.

Comment: @Jai Thank you.I tried it.But when I click the expand/collapse icon, there is still a problem.Attachment is a screenshot.If you have time, please help me look at it.

Comment: there are several bugs around images in treeCells (don't have the references handy, please search the bug parade) ... afair, without workarounds

Comment: found the bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8209017 ... which has a workaround: null the graphic of the checkbox